# What are some real-world programming applications of using the binary literal instead of the decimal literal?

Tags: java, binary, decimal

When should we use binary instead of decimal? What are some real life applications of using the binary literal in any programming language?

Comment: As long as you understand that int ``x = 0b00001101;`` is exactly the same as writing ``x = 13;``. I sometimes use the binary literal form if I'm working at the bit level, because it's easier for me to envision the bits this way.

Answer (score 1):

Bit manipulations. There are many tasks using this.

E.g. you need to check that all switches (e.g. of the light) are on or off. You have many of them (e.g. 32).

You can implement it using `boolean array`:

```
class SwitchControl {

    private final boolean[] lights = new boolean[32];

    public void turnOnLight(int n) {
        lights[n] = true;
    }

    public void turnOffLight(int n) {
        lights[n] = false;
    }

    public boolean isLightOn(int n) {
        return lights[n];
    }

    public boolean isAllLightsOn() {
        for (boolean light : lights)
            if (!light)
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAllLightsOff() {
        for (boolean light : lights)
            if (light)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

But easiest and more efficient implementation is to use `int` as a holder of `32 bits’ or` light switchers`:

```
class SwitchControl {

    private int lights;

    public void turnOnLight(int n) {
        lights |= 1 << n;
    }

    public void turnOffLight(int n) {
        lights &= ~(1 << n);
    }

    public boolean isLightOn(int n) {
        return (lights & 1 << n) != 0;
    }

    public boolean isAllLightsOn() {
        return lights == 0xFFFFFFFF;    // all 32 bits are set
    }

    public boolean isAllLightsOff() {
        return lights == 0;    // all 32 bits are cleared
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, "easies" depending on how familiar you are with this approach and how comfortable you are with bit manipulation.